# New UIViewController frame is 320x480 instead of larger screen size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I updated Xcode today.

AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.vc];
    self.window.rootViewController = nc;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

ViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGRect f = self.view.frame;
    f =[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    self.view.frame = f;
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

The frame is showing as 320x480. I can clearly see more space around the view, but it's black. Why is the view not filling out? There is no XIB.

Comment: You need to add the proper launch screen images or the launch screen file to properly support bigger screens.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Not intuitive!

Comment: Call [self.view setNeedsLayout]; after setting its frame.